# mandFields[i].css is not a function Line 6

Tags: jquery

I get that error with the following code. anyone know why?

```
function validateAdminInput(){
    var mandFields = $('.mand');

    for(i=0; i< mandFields.length;i++){
        if (mandFields[i].value == ""){
            mandFields[i].css('border','solid red 1px');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mandFields[i]` gives you the underlying DOM element. You need to wrap it in a `$(mandFields[i])` if you want to access the jQuery `.css()` function.

Or:

```
function validateAdminInput() {
    $('.mand').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('border','solid red 1px');
        }
    });
}
```

or even:

```
function validateAdminInput() {
    $('.mand[value=""]').css('border','solid red 1px');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `mandFields[i]` or `mandFields.get(i)` you retreive the DOM element, so there no method like `.css()` which are provided by jQuery.

Use the `eq()` methode to retreive the jQuery object : `mandFields.eq(i).css`