# jQuery find() throws `css method not found` error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
var done = function(el) {
        var tds = el.parent().parent().find('td');
        for (var i in tds) {
            tds[i].css('backgroundColor', 'green');
        }
    };
done($(this));
```

Where `$(this)` points to the element inside `td` tag - so I'm getting all nearby `td` tags and changing background color on them.

The problem is that it throws an error that `tds[i].css` function is undefined.

Doing this in clear javascript, with passing `this`, works perfectly, like so:

```
var done = function(el) {
        var tds = el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td');
        for (var i in tds) {
            tds[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        }
    };
done(this);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `$(tds[i]).css('backgroundColor', 'green');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mandFields\[i\].css is not a function Line 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759507/mandfieldsi-css-is-not-a-function-line-6)

Comment: el.parent().parent().find('td').css('backgroundColor', 'green'); is enough

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this :

```
var done = function(el) {
        var tds = el.parent().parent().find('td');

        $(tds).each(function(){
            this.css('backgroundColor', 'green');
        });
    };
done($(this));
```